# Need the ID of the current row inserted within a transaction

Tags: postgresql, go

Within a **transaction** I'm **inserting a row**.

How can I **access and return the ID of the inserted row**.
As you can see in the code below(**See under comment // Return last Inserted ID.**) I tried to use the **LastInsertedId()** function, but it gives me an error back.

Btw, I'm using Postgres.

What am I missing here?
Thx!

```
/**
 * Creates order and returns its ID.
 */
func createOrder(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (orderID int) {

    // Begin.
    tx, err := db.Begin()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Db query.
    sqlQuery := `INSERT INTO ORDER_CUSTOMER
        (CUSTOMER_ID)
        VALUES ($1)
        RETURNING ID`

    // Prepare.
    stmt, err := tx.Prepare(sqlQuery)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    // Defer Close.
    defer stmt.Close()

    customerEmail := validateSession(r)
    ID := getIDFromCustomer(customerEmail)
    order := order{}
    order.CustomerID = ID

    // Exec.
    ret, err := stmt.Exec(order.CustomerID)

    // Rollback.
    if err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
        e := errors.New(err.Error())
        msg.Warning = e.Error()
        tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "menu.gohtml", msg)
        return
    }

    // Return last Inserted ID.
    lastID, err := ret.LastInsertId()
    if err != nil {
        orderID = 0
    } else {
        orderID = int(lastID)
    }

    // Commit.
    tx.Commit()

    return orderID
} // createOrder
```

Here is a working solution for now, further improvement is welcomed.

```
/**
 * Creates order and returns its ID.
 */
func createOrder(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (orderID int) {

    // Begin.
    tx, err := db.Begin()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Db query.
    sqlQuery := `INSERT INTO ORDER_CUSTOMER
        (CUSTOMER_ID)
        VALUES ($1)
        RETURNING ID`

    // Prepare.
    stmt, err := tx.Prepare(sqlQuery)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    // Defer Close.
    defer stmt.Close()

    customerEmail := validateSession(r)
    ID := getIDFromCustomer(customerEmail)
    order := order{}
    order.CustomerID = ID

    // Exec.
    _, err = stmt.Exec(order.CustomerID)

    // Rollback.
    if err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
        e := errors.New(err.Error())
        msg.Warning = e.Error()
        tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "menu.gohtml", msg)
        return
    }

    // Return last Inserted ID.
    //lastID, err := ret.LastInsertId()
    err = stmt.QueryRow(order.CustomerID).Scan(&orderID)
    if err != nil {
        orderID = 0
    }

    // Commit.
    tx.Commit()

    return orderID
} // createOrder
```

Comment: try stmt.QueryRow(order.CustomerID) instead, then grab the id off the row.  see https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Stmt.QueryRow

Comment: you can use id as serial and then directly call a query from your code using max(id), which will give you last inserted row.In postgres, serial is same as sequence.

Comment: @saarrrr: thx that helped! I will update my question based with a working solution based on your hint.

Comment: THIS IS NOT SAFE. If another query inserts and commits you will get ITS id not yours.

Answer (score 5):

This happens because the postgresql driver you are using for go doesn't supports the `LastInsertedId()` function. You didn't say which driver you are using but I have had this issue working with `github.com/lib/pq`.

The answer to this is to use `QueryRow` insted of `Exec` in your original example. Just make sure you are using `RETURNING ID` on your query and treat it as if it was a select.

Here is an example (I didn't test this and I might be missing something but you get the idea):

```
func createOrder(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (orderID int) {

    // Begin.
    tx, err := db.Begin()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Db query.
    sqlQuery := `INSERT INTO ORDER_CUSTOMER
        (CUSTOMER_ID)
        VALUES ($1)
        RETURNING ID`

    // Prepare.
    stmt, err := tx.Prepare(sqlQuery)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    // Defer Close.
    defer stmt.Close()

    customerEmail := validateSession(r)
    ID := getIDFromCustomer(customerEmail)
    order := order{}
    order.CustomerID = ID

    // Exec.
    var orderID int // Or whatever type you are using
    err := stmt.QueryRow(order.CustomerID).Scan(&orderID)

    // Rollback.
    if err != nil {
        //if something goes wrong set the orderID to 0 as in your original code
        orderID = 0
        tx.Rollback()
        e := errors.New(err.Error())
        msg.Warning = e.Error()
        tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "menu.gohtml", msg)
        return
    }

    // Commit.
    tx.Commit()

    return orderID
} // createOrder
```